# IOS View how to make it see-through and completely disapper

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, tableview

I have a TableView and I have a view that is on top of the TableView so as you scroll down on the TableView that view is always displayed . What I now want is that when a user is scrolling up on the TableView I want that overhead view to completely disappear and not be seen at all . Right now when the user Scrolls up the View becomes completely white but it is still visible. Is there anyway to hide it from view ? If it helps the overhead view is only 50.0 in height

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y + 0) {
            // TableView Moving up
          View2.isHidden = true
            View2.alpha = 0

        }

    }
```

Here is an Image and the TopView is covering part of the TableView.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: Yes just posted an image

Comment: Assign this view as headerview to the tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `UITableHeaderView` like below.

This is just example, you have to changes as per your requirement.

Find the `data` array as below.

```
for i in 1...15 {
    data.append("New Object \(i)")
}
```

Now Implement `UITableViewDataSource` method like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
    cell.tmpValue.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let lblTemp = UILabel(frame: headerView.bounds)
    lblTemp.text = "Header View"

    headerView.addSubview(lblTemp)

    return headerView
}
```

Output will be like this,

[image]

Here `CustomCell` is your custom TableView cell.

You can even create Custom XIB for HeaderView and do accordingly as per your requirement.

FYI, For HeaderView to scroll up while scrolling, your TableView's style should be `Grouped`.

Hope it works for you.